# Init data in NavigationLink.onAppear() used in the next view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I want to display `ViewB()` from `ViewA()`. In `ViewA()`, some data of a singleton object will be computed, then used in `View(B)`. All of that is done through a NavigationLink():

```
struct ViewA(): View
{
  var body: some View
  {
    NavigationLink
    {
      ViewB().onAppear()
      {
         // Computing data for a Singleton object
      }
    }
    label:
    {
      Text("Continue")
    }
  }
}
```

When I reach the `ViewB()`, I'm facing some nulls values. Using the debuger, I learnt that this is actually because the View(B) is initialized before the user could 'compute' the data, when taping the "Continue" text label.

How can I compute data in a view that will be used in a second view if this latest is initialized before I could do some processing?

Comment: Always account for nil values. Especially with SwiftUI

Answer (score -1):

One way to solve this issue is to use an `@EnvironmentObject` property wrapper to pass the singleton object between the views. This way, you can compute the data for the singleton object in ViewA and then access it in ViewB, and the singleton object will be updated automatically when the data changes.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to use an `@EnvironmentObject` property wrapper:

```
class SingletonObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var computedData: String = ""
}

struct ViewA: View {
    @StateObject var singletonObject = SingletonObject()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: ViewB().environmentObject(singletonObject)) {
                Text("Continue")
            }
            .onAppear {
                // Compute data for the singleton object
                singletonObject.computedData = "Data computed in ViewA"
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var singletonObject: SingletonObject

    var body: some View {
        Text("Data computed in ViewA: \(singletonObject.computedData)")
    }
}
```